# WCF Rest Service over SSL - ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: .net, rest, wcf, ssl, certificate

I have a WCF Rest service over SSL. A couple of years ago I was able to test it on my development machine with Postman. I'm using a self signed certificate made with MakeCert. I've installed it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Postman says "Could not get any response". Clicking on the link to the service opens Chrome where it gives the ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID message. I've made a testing application and that works. I've read that Chrome is being more particular about well formed certificates. After trying a number of ideas from around the web I'm at the end of my rope. I'm not sure what specifics to provide from my project to help diagnose this. Let me know.

Comment: Is only Chrome that gives this error?

Comment: Given the  missing details about what you actually tried (*"After trying a number of ideas from around the web"*) I can only guess that this the same problem as commonly seen by others with Chrome. Accordingly I've marked it as a duplicate. If you feel that this is not a duplicate please add enough details to your question which show how it differs from [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID+chrome+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and which help in debugging the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich SOLVED The referenced question had the links in it that I needed to resolve my issue. I never came across that question since I was focused on the err_cert_common_name_invalid error. It turns out that Google explains the situation nicely. I'm on Win7 and had to install PowerShell 6, learn how to import a module so I could run New-SelfSignedCertificateEx then find a parameter combination that works. MakeCert cannot define Subject Alternate Names which is what was missing.